# Is it appropriate to ask if whether someone is in possession of the solutions of a completed online olympiad?

Tags: discussion

I want to clarify whether I could ask if someone has the solutions to a completed exam. I presume my question arises mainly due to less clarity with the specific-refernce and the soft-question tag.

Note:- The exam happened in May 2020 and the results are out nearly 10 months back and I haven't been able to find the solutions to the Invitational Round of that Physics olympiad anywhere.

The link to the closed question is down below for reference. The question is closed citing the reason (correctly) that it wasn't about a conceptual physics topic, but I am unsure as I thought the soft-question tag was for that kind of question. Now, I have edited the question from before into what I hope is more appropriate. Although, I am still confused now whether the specific-reference tag is applicable or not also.

[Does anyone have the solutions of the invitational round of OPhO 2020?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/641088/does-anyone-have-the-solutions-of-the-invitational-round-of-opho-2020)

Thank You!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Asking for the solutions to a specific set of physics exercises is not a question about physics as a natural science. It is also neither a request for a resource recommendation, nor a request for a paper containing specific physics. Hence it is not on-topic on our site.

Note that asking for the solutions of the questions directly will likely be off-topic by [our homework-and-exercises policy](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/715/50583).

Comment: So, will it be better if I individually post the questions and show where I face difficulty?

Comment: @Aadhavan No, as I said, asking for the solutions of the questions directly will be off-topic, too. Showing your work is good, but does not, in general, suffice to make a homework-and-exercises question on-topic. However, if you have *specific, conceptual* questions that arise when trying to solve these exercises, you're welcome to ask them

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's all clarified now.